# Compilation error: constructor in class cannot be applied to given types

Tags: java, enums, compiler-errors, extends, superclass

Im trying to create a subclass object using an enum from the super class but when I try to create the object in the subclass I get this error.

```
error: constructor Payroll in class Payroll cannot be applied to given types;
        public PayClaim(int hours, PayLevel level){
                                                  ^
  required: PayLevel
  found:    no arguments
  reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
1 error
```

This is my superclass Payroll

```
public class Payroll{
    
    
    static double OVERTIME_RATE = 1.5;

    static int REGULAR_WEEK = 40;
    static int LEVEL_ONE_PAY = 15;
    static int LEVEL_TWO_PAY = 25;
    static int LEVEL_THREE_PAY = 40;
    
    public enum PayLevel{
        ONE, TWO, THREE
    }
    
    private PayLevel levels;
    public Payroll(PayLevel levels){
        this.levels = levels;
    }
    
    public PayLevel getPayLevel(){
        return levels;
    }
    
    public static void main (String [] args) {
        Payroll.OVERTIME_RATE = 1.75;
        Payroll.REGULAR_WEEK = 40;
        Payroll.LEVEL_ONE_PAY = 12;
        System.out.println(Payroll.calculatePay(35, Payroll.PayLevel.ONE));
    }
    
    public static double calculatePay(int noHoursWorked, PayLevel level){
    //do stuff
    }
    
}
```

And this is my subclass PayClaim

```
public class PayClaim extends Payroll{
    
    
    int noHoursWorked;
    public Payroll.PayLevel payLevel;
    double calculatedPay = 0;
    
    public static void main (String [] args) {
        PayClaim p = new PayClaim(1, Payroll.PayLevel.ONE);
        System.out.println(p);
    }
    
    public PayClaim(int hours, PayLevel level){
        
        if(hours > 80 || hours < 1){
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        }
        else{
            noHoursWorked = hours;
            payLevel = level;
        }
    }
    
    public int getNoHoursWorked(){
        return noHoursWorked;
    }
    
    public PayLevel getPayLevel(){
        return payLevel;
    }
    
    public double getClaculatedPay(){
        return calculatedPay;
    }
    
    public void setCalculatedPay(double pay){
        //
    }
    
    public String toString(){
        //

}
```

My apologies if I missed something trivial its just that the code wont even compile so I'm really struggling to find just where I'm going wrong here.

Comment: I was able to fix this myself by first, remove the extends Payroll in class definition. Then the only difference was when you have the Class PayClaim constructor instead of writing PayLevel level you have to write Payroll.PayLevel level. Then it works like a charm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the answer you are looking for is very simple. If you invoke the parent constructor to the subclass, this should resolve the compilation problems. You can do this by using the following changes. The change I made is at the beginning of the constructor, it simply calls the parents constructor to create an object, since it is a subclass.

```
public class PayClaim extends Payroll{
    
    
    int noHoursWorked;
    public Payroll.PayLevel payLevel;
    double calculatedPay = 0;
    
    public static void main (String [] args) {
        PayClaim p = new PayClaim(1, Payroll.PayLevel.ONE);
        System.out.println(p);
    }
    
    public PayClaim(int hours, PayLevel level){
    enter code here

        super(level);
        
        if(hours > 80 || hours < 1){
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        }
        else{
            noHoursWorked = hours;
            payLevel = level;
        }
    }
    
    public int getNoHoursWorked(){
        return noHoursWorked;
    }
    
    public PayLevel getPayLevel(){
        return payLevel;
    }
    
    public double getClaculatedPay(){
        return calculatedPay;
    }
    
    public void setCalculatedPay(double pay){
        //
    }
    
    public String toString(){
        //

}
```